# How does HashSet check two objects?

Tags: java, hash

```
class TestA extends Foo{
   private String a;
   private String b;
   private String c;

   public int hashcode() {
     // Use some inbuilt hashcode generator over a, b, c.
   }

   public boolean equals(Object a) {
     // a, b, c instance variables should match
   }
}
```

```
class TestB Extends Foo{
   private String a;
   private String b;
   private String c;

   public int hashcode() {
     // Same as Test A class implementation
   }

   public boolean equals(Object a) {
     // Same as Test A class implementation
   }
}
```

Say I add the following object into a HashSet:

```
TestA a = new TestA("a", "b", "c")

set.add(a);
```

Now, if I check the following object b is in the hashset, will `set.contains(b)` always return true?

```
TestB B = new TestB("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: Since `TestA.equals()` only returns `true` when the parameter is a `TestA` object, and `TestB.equals()` only returns `true` when the parameter is a `TestB` object, `set.contains(b)` will return `false`.

Comment: Maybe you should add your hashset too. `Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<>();`

Comment: Put _equals_ into Foo. I guess in this case a,b,c should belong to Foo too.

Comment: Also, why don't you just try and get the hashcodes? I bet they will be different because classes are different etc.

Answer (score -1):

Since your HashSet should be `HashSet<TestA>` you shouldn't be even able to compile passing TestB instance as a parameter into *contains*.

Comment: What if `set` is a `HashSet<Object>`? It can contain both `TestA` and `TestB` objects at the same time.

Comment: Both classes extend base class Foo

Comment: You should be fine if it's defined as HashSet of Foo. TestA and TestB instances will be equivalent so yes it will be true. And defining HashSet of Object is just not a safe practice. I would try to put _equals_ and _hashCode_ into Foo too and not in A and B.

Comment: @Andrei *"so yes it will be true"* No it won't, because the `TestA` implementation of `equals()` will fail the standard test that checks if the parameter is also a `TestA` object, so `equals()` would return `false` when parameter is a `TestB` object, and vice-versa, meaning that `set.contain(b)` would return `false`. --- Unless the `equals()` implementation is explicitly code to know about `TestB` too, and that is extremely unlikely. Of course, with seeing the implementation of `equals()`, we can only guess, but ....